# error C2664: 'errno_t strcpy_s(char *,rsize_t,const char *)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [512]' to 'rsize_t'

Tags: c++, string, winsock, tcpsocket, tps

Code:

```
 #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015" 
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH   512

class Client {
public:
    Client(char* servername)
    {
        szServerName = servername;
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    bool Start() {
        WSADATA wsaData;

        // Initialize Winsock
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        if(iResult != 0)
        {
            printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
            return false;
        }

        struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                        *ptr = NULL,
                        hints;

        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;        
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

        // Resolve the server address and port
        iResult = getaddrinfo(szServerName, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0)
        {
            printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }

        ptr = result;

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }

        // Connect to server
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };

    // Free the resouces
    void Stop() {
        int iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }

        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    };

    // Send message to server
    bool Send(char* szMsg)
    {

        int iResult = send(ConnectSocket, szMsg, strlen(szMsg), 0);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            Stop();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };

    // Receive message from server
    bool Recv()
    {
        char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
        int iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);

        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            char msg[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
            memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            strcpy_s(msg, recvbuf, iResult);

            printf("Received: %s\n", msg);

            return true;
        }


        return false;
    }

private:
    char* szServerName;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
};


int main(int argc, CHAR* argv[]) 
{
    std::string msg;

    Client client("127.0.0.1");

    if (!client.Start())
        return 1;

    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "Send: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, msg);

        // Close the connection when user enter "close"
        if (msg.compare("close") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        client.Send((char*)msg.c_str());
        client.Recv();
    }

    client.Stop();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH   512

int main() {

    WSADATA wsaData;

    // Initialize Winsock
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if(iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;      // Internet address family is unspecified so that either an IPv6 or IPv4 address can be returned
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    // Requests the socket type to be a stream socket for the TCP protocol
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Create a SOCKET for the server to listen for client connections
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    // To listen on a socket
    if ( listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listen failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ClientSocket;

    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    int iSendResult;

    // reveice until the client shutdown the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            char msg[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
            memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            strcpy_s(msg, recvbuf, iResult);

            printf("Received: %s\n", msg);

            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);

            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            printf("Bytes sent: %ld\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            //return 1;
        }
    } while (iResult > 0);

    // Free the resouces
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

> error C2664: 'errno_t strcpy_s(char *,rsize_t,const char *)' : cannot
>   convert parameter 2 from 'char [512]' to 'rsize_t'
>
> error C2664: 'errno_t strcpy_s(char *,rsize_t,const char *)' : cannot
>   convert parameter 2 from 'char [512]' to 'rsize_t'
>
> IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "strcpy_s" matches
>   the argument list
>               argument types are: (char [512], char [512], int)

---

### I have been trying to fix this problem. Please help.

New code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH   128

int main() {

    WSADATA wsaData;

    // Initialize Winsock
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if(iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;      // Internet address family is unspecified so that either an IPv6 or IPv4 address can be returned
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    // Requests the socket type to be a stream socket for the TCP protocol
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Create a SOCKET for the server to listen for client connections
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    // To listen on a socket
    if ( listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listen failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ClientSocket;

    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    int iSendResult;

    // reveice until the client shutdown the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            char msg[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
            memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            strcpy_s(msg, iResult, recvbuf);

            printf("Received: %s\n", msg);

            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);

            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            printf("Bytes sent: %ld\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            //return 1;
        }
    } while (iResult > 0);

    // Free the resouces
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

New error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/55IUF.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the parameters in the wrong order.

```
errno_t strcpy_s(char *dest, rsize_t size, const char *src);
```

You put the `src` in the `size` param and the `size` in the `src` param.